# Pandas impute values from grouped dataframe to another dataframe with an object

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For the dataset I'm working with, I want to impute null values with medians grouped by country. I have created a grouped table (median_data in the code below), which contains all the median values by country.

I need to do this median calculation and imputation in separate steps since the end goal is to create an object with 'fit' and 'transform' methods, so that I can calculate medians based only on the train data, and impute to the test data.

Here's dummy data I'm working with:

```
data =  [['A', 10, 20, np.nan, np.nan, 50, 30], ['A', 2, 1, 5, np.nan, 34, 35], ['A', 13, 212, 3, 6, np.nan, 37],
         ['B', 120, 230, 53, np.nan, 63, 23], ['B', 22, 115, 15, 61, 4, 15], ['B', np.nan, 22, 12, np.nan, np.nan, 31],
         ['C', 105, 120, np.nan, 22, 520, 3], ['C', 26, 11, 15, np.nan, 34, 3], ['C', 13, np.nan, 13, 234, np.nan, 10],
         ['D', 101, 220, 654, 143, 634, 123], ['D', 32, 21, 61, 24, np.nan, 32], ['D', 11, 72, 23, np.nan, 534, 30]
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'])


median_data = df.groupby('Country').median().reset_index()
```

Currently not using an object, just trying to figure out how to do it. Using loops isn't working. I tried different iterations, here's where I'm at right now:

```
df_new = df.copy()
for country in median_data.Country:
    country_data = median_data[median_data.Country == country].copy()
    for col in median_data.columns[2:]:
        df_new[col] = df_new[col].fillna(country_data[col])
```

**The dataset, df:**

[image]

**The table with medians grouped by 'Country':**

[image]

**Result from the code above (clearly incorrect).**
As an example, col4 for Country A should be [6, 6, 6], but the values I get are [6, 61, 6]:

[image]

Is there a way to separately calculate median values and impute them? Efficiency is not my primary concern, but an efficient solution would obviously be preferred.

**Update:** While this method seems to work initially, it doesn't achieve what I need it to. I specifically need to be able to store the median values somehow and then use them to impute to the test set as well. Since the train and test sets are by definition of unequal sizes, using update or combine_first wouldn't work, since the row numbers wouldn't correspond and the imputed values would be wrong, even if somehow the number of rows was the same.

**Update 2:** The solution provided by @jezrael works, but with a catch.

```
median_data = df1.groupby('Country').median()
df2.update(df2[['Country']].merge(median_data, on='Country',  how='left'), overwrite=False)
```

This code will work, but first the datasets need to have their indices reset with reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True). This works for now, but maybe resetting indices will mess with model training etc. To be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.DataFrame.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `median`:

```
df.update(df.groupby('Country').transform('median'), overwrite=False)
print (df)
   Country   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5  col6
0        A   10.0   20.0    4.0    6.0   50.0    30
1        A    2.0    1.0    5.0    6.0   34.0    35
2        A   13.0  212.0    3.0    6.0   42.0    37
3        B  120.0  230.0   53.0   61.0   63.0    23
4        B   22.0  115.0   15.0   61.0    4.0    15
5        B   71.0   22.0   12.0   61.0   33.5    31
6        C  105.0  120.0   14.0   22.0  520.0     3
7        C   26.0   11.0   15.0  128.0   34.0     3
8        C   13.0   65.5   13.0  234.0  277.0    10
9        D  101.0  220.0  654.0  143.0  634.0   123
10       D   32.0   21.0   61.0   24.0  584.0    32
11       D   11.0   72.0   23.0   83.5  534.0    30
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('Country').transform('median'))
    col1   col2  col3   col4   col5  col6
0   10.0   20.0   4.0    6.0   42.0    35
1   10.0   20.0   4.0    6.0   42.0    35
2   10.0   20.0   4.0    6.0   42.0    35
3   71.0  115.0  15.0   61.0   33.5    23
4   71.0  115.0  15.0   61.0   33.5    23
5   71.0  115.0  15.0   61.0   33.5    23
6   26.0   65.5  14.0  128.0  277.0     3
7   26.0   65.5  14.0  128.0  277.0     3
8   26.0   65.5  14.0  128.0  277.0     3
9   32.0   72.0  61.0   83.5  584.0    32
10  32.0   72.0  61.0   83.5  584.0    32
11  32.0   72.0  61.0   83.5  584.0    32
```

Alternative solution with [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df1 = df.combine_first(df.groupby('Country').transform('median'))
print (df1)
   Country   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5  col6
0        A   10.0   20.0    4.0    6.0   50.0    30
1        A    2.0    1.0    5.0    6.0   34.0    35
2        A   13.0  212.0    3.0    6.0   42.0    37
3        B  120.0  230.0   53.0   61.0   63.0    23
4        B   22.0  115.0   15.0   61.0    4.0    15
5        B   71.0   22.0   12.0   61.0   33.5    31
6        C  105.0  120.0   14.0   22.0  520.0     3
7        C   26.0   11.0   15.0  128.0   34.0     3
8        C   13.0   65.5   13.0  234.0  277.0    10
9        D  101.0  220.0  654.0  143.0  634.0   123
10       D   32.0   21.0   61.0   24.0  584.0    32
11       D   11.0   72.0   23.0   83.5  534.0    30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out. I tried combine_first as well, and it didn't seem to work. The difference here appears to be that you used .transform('median') instead of .median(). Do you know what the difference between the two is?

Edit: I think I got it, it's that .transform would create a dataframe with the same number of rows, i.e. with the values already "imputed", while .median() creates a smaller one with just the median values. Is this correct?

Comment: @MushyMush - yes, if use `groupby.transform` values are repeated per groups, not aggregate like `groupby.median()` . difference `DataFrame.update` working inplace, need `overwrite=False` for replace missing values `combine_first` not working inplace and by default replace missing values.

Comment: @MushyMush - exactly, you got it.

Comment: apologies for coming back to this, but this is the issue I initially thought I would face. While the method you described above works outside of an object, I cannot use this technique inside an object. I need to be able to calculate the median values from the train set and impute them in the test set. This is not possible using the transform method, since we get a "pre-imputed" dataset that we use to replace the corresponding null values.

Comment: @MushyMush Then use `median_data = df1.groupby('Country').median()` and `df2.update(df2[['Country']].merge(median_data, on='Country',  how='left'), overwrite=False)`

Comment: @MushyMush or `df1.combine_first(df2[['Country']].merge(median_data, on='Country',  how='left'))`

Comment: I'm using your suggestions as a starting point but so far neither is working. update() returns 'None', and combine first adds extra rows, and messes up the merge.

Comment: May have figured out the issue. To use update, the indices need to match. Train test split keeps the original indices, so you'd have to use reset index and drop the original indices. Updated the post. Now the question is, do indices matter for model training etc?